# Actionscript 2 timer decreases fast

Tags: javascript, actionscript, actionscript-2, flash-cs5

So, I have this timer in 2 scenes. The timer in the 1st scene works perfectly. However, when I tried it to the 2nd scene the timer goes so fast.
I have 2 set of codes:

```
_root.timer = 10;
clearInterval(id);
id = setInterval (function ()
           { 
                _root.timer--;
                if(timer==0)
                {
                    gotoAndStop(65);
                }
           }, 1000);
```

AND this:

```
timer = 10;
timer.text= timer;
countdown = function(){
            timer--;
            if(timer==0){
                         clearInterval(countdownInterval);
                         gotoAndStop(65);
                        }
                      }
countdownInterval = setInterval(countdown,1000);
```

I'm aware that 1000 milliseconds = 1 second. I just don't know what causes the timer to decrease fast in the second scene. What do you think?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the second scene, timer decrase 2 times faster, because there is two setInterval running, _root.timer will equal timer in two stages. So there is two functions calling each second, and it each function decrases same variable.

**Solution:** in second scene, rename timer variable to timer2 or timernew.

Comment: Got it. Thanks. Uhm, Is it possible to pause and play the timer? By play i mean, without resetting it. It'll play where it stopped. Perhaps, by using a button. Thank you very much.

Comment: I don't know AS2 implemation of timer, but in AS3 its pretty eays, create timer object with new Timer(); and just use timer.reset(); timer.start(); But if you define the function to global, its eays to clearInterval and setInterval.